# like-vim emacs ruby indentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim, emacs, indentation

ruby-mode from svn, looks equal to 1.1 version

here is emacs indentation of hash

```
User.all({
       :joins => :account,
       :conditions => {:delete_at => nil}
     })
```

here is the same in vim

```
User.all({
  :joins => :account,
  :conditions => {:delete_at => nil}
})
```

How to make emacs indent like vim in ruby-mode?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try <kbd>M-x customize-mode</kbd>; you'll see options for customizing Ruby indentation. Looks like you may want to change "Ruby Deep Indent Paren" to nil.

Comment: Likewise: (setq ruby-deep-indent-paren nil)